Jackrabbit Oak disable versioning
I want to setup document archive for my application. Documents will be added only once and won't be updated. I am using mongoDb as document storage. I also defined custom node type with various properties using code:
Workspace workspace = jackrabbitSession.getWorkspace();
NodeTypeManager ntManager = workspace.getNodeTypeManager();
PropertyDefinitionTemplate property = ntManager.createPropertyDefinitionTemplate();
property.setName("filename");
property.setRequiredType(PropertyType.STRING);

When I archive document, every string, boolean, and int properties are stored as Objects in mongoDB.

I suspect that this r191f49bcd8c-0-1 is some kind of version identifier. Is there a way to turn it off as this node will never be updated. Ideally, I would like to see the values of attributes directly and be able to query them in mongoDb easily.

No, this is an implementation detail based on Oak's internal architecture.
You are not supposed to interact with MongoDB directly. Well, maybe except for debugging.
